# How to Put validation in dynamic display column

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have `<mat-select>` with `ngFor` which displays a list of rows from the table. I need to put validation in column type that I should be able to select only 1 key and then, the user should not be able to select key in type dropdown.

```
// Code for html(Angular 7)
<!-- Column for Type-->
<ng-container matColumnDef="type">Type
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Type</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Type" [(ngModel)]="element.type" (selectionChange)="checkTypeValidation(element,element.type)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let type of typeColumn" [value]="type">
      {{ type }} 
      <div *ngIf = "element.type === "></div>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

This is the code which displays the type of row. It's a `mat-select` with 6 options. However, for now, there is no validation. You can choose every row as key, time, segment.

I want to put a validation that only one row can be of type key:

```
// Code for Typescript
  typeColumn = [
    'None',
    'Time',
    'Segment',
    'Key',
    'Input',
    'Quantile'
  ];
```

This typescript code gives you the option to choose the option in mat-dropdown for Type column. I should be able to select only one row as key.

Comment: So you want one type only (maximum) once selected in your whole table ? ONE Select which has Time. One Select that has Key. And maybe all other dont have anything selected ?

Comment: And does it have to be just invalid (showing ErrorMessage) or can it also be not-selectable ? (You would have to unselect the Select with 'Key' to select it on another one)

Comment: @Jonaris Anything will do...either it can show error code that Two keys cannot be selected or you can disable the Key option once key has been selected from dropdown

Comment: say there are 10 rows in that 10 rows I should be able to select only 1 row as Key type and rest can be time,segment,quantile etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the option as disabled whenever selected and enabled it again when changed:

```html
<mat-select placeholder="Type" (selectionChange)="changed($event)">
```

```ts
  changed(event){
    if(event.value.type == 'Key'){
       //when there was a value previously, allow it again
       if(this.previous[event.source.id] != undefined){
         this.typeColumn[this.previous[event.source.id]].allowed = true;
       }
       this.previous[event.source.id] = event.value.index;
       //disable the selected option
       this.typeColumn[event.value.index].allowed = false;
    }
  }
```

See the Demo for detailed code.

I'm sure you can build a solution from this:

### [Full Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anus7w)

Comment: In your code if I select Key from drop-down then Key gets disabled and if i select segment then segment also gets disabled.I want this validation only for Key. I should be able to choose Segment as many times I want

Comment: Hi Your code works like a charm..thank you so much ... Can you also please tell me if i want to put a validation like there should at least 1 Segment 1 input and 1 Time then how to do it.

Comment: if you want them to have "at least" 1 of each of them you would have to display an error somewhere when it is not. You would either need a [validator and reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) or you would just check on `selectionChange` if you have all of them marked (maybe add another attribute to typeColumn to tell if it is selected).